# New wireless card in a x301 Thinkpad

Tags: windows-8, thinkpad, wireless-card

I am trying to install an Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6200 into my Levovo x301 Thinkpad. I have a half card and have the gray and black wires plugged in. I replaced the BIOS with a version that does not whitelist wireless cards.

[image]

Why won't Windows 8 recognize this card? Am I supposed to use the other wires instead? I replaced my old card because Intel stopped making drivers for it for Windows.

Comment: Does it show up in Device Manager at all? Event with the wrong/no antenna attached it should still show up in DM.  Are you sure it's seated fully/properly? Have you tested the adapter to ensure it works (like by inserting it into another notebook)?

Comment: Have you confirmed no physical WIFI control switches are toggled off?

Comment: It does not show up in the device manager. I do not have another notebook to test the card one. Before I redid the bios, I did get the bios error though. Wifi switch is on.

Comment: I swapped wireless cards with my netbook. My netbook recognizes the 6200. The new wireless card (unlabeled) is not detected in my x301. I switched to the white cable on the AUX and the black on the MAIN

Comment: Note: I can see a PCI Serial Port and PCI Simple Communications Controller in my other devices in the device manager.

Comment: I don't like that metal bracket-adapter thing. :)  Have you tried dismounting it form that and instead putting the card (without the metal bracket) into the other "9BGHA" socket in the picture?

Comment: I hate to ask an obvious question, but if you're seeing devices in Device manager under "other", have you tried manually installing the drivers for this card?

Comment: I put the device into the other port. That did not work either. I have been manually installing the driver with `wireless_15.3.50_De64.exe` after I remove PCI Serial Port and PCI Simple Communications controller but the driver just adds them back again?

Comment: I added legacy drivers through device manager and all of the drivers for 6200 say `This device is not working properly because Windows cannot load the drivers required for this device. (Code 31)`

Comment: Maybe you should rollback the bios to the previous version.

Comment: How would I do that? The x301 bios whitelists cards unless you mod it. My bios is currently modded.

Comment: It also does not work with a 6300. Would a fresh install of Windows do the trick?

Comment: Fresh installs did not work. Tried to install Ubuntu and that was a no go.

Comment: I ended up getting a usb dongle